# Fancytree update tree with new data

Tags: fancytree

I've been trying to use reload() to update the tree to new data but the whole tree reloads which is not wanted. Just want that the nodes get updated with the new data which will contain child data for the nodes. I do not want to reload the whole tree insted i want to keep the current nodes that I've expanded.

New to fancytree, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
 var rootNode = $(el).fancytree("getRootNode");
 rootNode.removeChildren();
 rootNode.addChildren(newTreeData);
```

Comment: Where to trigger the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `node.load();` This is applied to a single node, so you'll need to loop through all nodes you want re-loaded.

The `load` function is explained here: http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#load